# Capture Japanese Letters From Keyboard Event

Tags: java, keyboard-events, jna, cjk

I have used **"kwhat/jnativehook"** (Global keyboard and mouse listeners for Java.) to
capture global keyboard events.

I have changed the keyboard language to Japanese using windows IME. But still I'm getting English letter from **NativeKeyEvent**

```
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
    displayEventInfo(e);
}
```

Any idea to capture Japanese letters which was fired using keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably does not support japanese letters. You might be forced to make a mapping `getKeyId()` -> japanese letter.

Comment: @Ben is there any other libraries which can do the needful ?

Comment: Nothing with the capabilities of jnativehook that I know about.